# ld: warning: directory not found

Tags: macos, makefile, ld

I have a Makefile in which I set a library path for the linker. Because the code depends on libraries that lives in different directories depending on how they are installed (fink, macports, source,...), I include all possible locations in the library path. 
When I compile on linux, ld does not care if a directory in the library path exists or not, but on OS X, ld gives the ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L...' warning if one or more of the directories does not exist.

I was wondering if there is a way to test if a directory exists in the Makefile before setting the path? Currently, I have this in the Makefile

```
LIBS    = -L${PREFIX}/lib \
          -L${HOME}/lib \
          -L/opt/local/lib \
          -L/sw/lib
```

I apologize if this is a trivial question, but I am not particularly good with Make or Makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build `LIBS` piece-by-piece, using:

```
ifneq (,$(wildcard ${PREFIX}/lib/.))
    LIBS += -L${PREFIX}/lib
endif

ifneq (,$(wildcard ${HOME}/lib/.))
    LIBS += -L${HOME}/lib
endif
```

etc.